# CloudKit Cursor Error and Failing to Return all Rows - Encountered an error fetching records

Tags: core-data, swift3, fetch

I am trying to retrieve all records from a CloudKit database table in order to compare with an array.  When I make the query from CloudKit, I am getting a general error.  I usually get some records back, but not the full set.  The table only has about 6500 records.  Using a predicate of true, i.e., no predicate, I get the same error.  The number of rows returned is different each time before the error occurs.

Full error:

```
<CKQuery: 0x618000423e40; recordType=ActionFigureSale, predicate=saleEndTime > CAST(422923500.000000, "NSDate")> errored for <CKError 0x60000085b6c0: "Internal Error" (1/1000); "Encountered an error fetching records">
```

I have tried setting the resultLimit to 1000, but get the same error multiple times as it queues multiple times.

```
        let publicDatabase = SharedData.sharedInstance.publicDatabase

        // let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(kSaleEndTime) > %@", saleEndTime)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: kActionFigureSaleRecord, predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: kSaleSourceUniqueId, ascending: true)]

        var queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        queryOperation.queuePriority = .veryHigh
        queryOperation.resultsLimit = 10000

        var actionFigureItemSaleCloudRecordArray = Array<CKRecord>()
        var actionFigureItemSaleCloudArray = Array<ItemSale>()

        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) -> Void in
            actionFigureItemSaleCloudRecordArray.append(record)

            let actionFigureReference = record.object(forKey: kActionFigureReference) as! CKReference

            ...

            actionFigureItemSaleCloudArray.append(itemSaleItemCloud)
        }

        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    #if DEBUG
                        print("WARNING:  Action Figure Sale iCloud query \(query) errored for \(error!)")
                    #endif

                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }
            }

            if cursor != nil {
                let newQueryOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
                newQueryOperation.cursor = cursor
                newQueryOperation.resultsLimit = queryOperation.resultsLimit
                newQueryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock

                queryOperation = newQueryOperation

                publicDatabase!.add(queryOperation)
                return

            }
            else {
                completion(actionFigureItemSaleCloudArray, nil)
                return
            }
        }

        publicDatabase!.add(queryOperation)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error and I was able to solve this by looking at the userInfo nested in CKError. The code below is part of my completionHandler in queryCompletionBlock:

```
if error is CKError {
    let ckerror = error as! CKError
    let info = ckerror.userInfo
    for inf in info {
        NSLog("User-Info:\(inf.key):\(inf.value)")
    }
    NSLog(error!.localizedDescription)
}
```

It came out, that my initial size of queryOperation.resultsLimit was too high. I decreased it to 400 and the error was gone.